# HTTP request not working on webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have this simple http request:

```
var http = require('http');

var data = JSON.stringify({
    some: 'data'
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'myhost.com',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/somePath',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, (response) => {
    var buffer = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {buffer += chunk;});
    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log(buffer);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Now, this works when I run it with node, but when I bundle it and run it on the webpack server, the request gets sent but **the callback function never gets called**. I know it has something to do with the request being asynchronous. Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: In webpack config do have `target` set as `node`? And why do you want to bundle backend serverside code into a webpack bundle?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty you are right, what was I thinking...

Answer (score 0):

I just used XMLHttpRequest like a normal human being...